# How to get a result from Activity to Fragment With Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have `MainActivity`, `ProductListFragment` and `ProductDetailActivity`.
ProductListFragment is a start fragment.
when I click a item of list in `ProductListFragment`, it goes to DetailActivity with action that i set in nav_graph.

```
  val action = ProductListFragmentDirections.actionProductListFragmentToProductDetailActivity(productId)
  findNavController().navigate(action)
```

and when I click up-button or press back-button, `DetailActivity` is finished() and it goes back to ProductListFragment.
in this case, i want to get a result when the DetailActivity is finished() like onActivityResult() callback in ProductListFragment.
so what kind of method should i use to get a result???
is there any way to get a result by using Navigation component or findNavcontroller?

Comment: What's the reason you consider that the `Detail` page must be an `Activity` but not a `Fragment`?

Comment: @SamChen There is no specific reason that I use Activity. i just made it into an activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start an Activity and receive a result back from that Activity, you should use the [Activity Result APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

This is the one and only correct API to use for this particular case - there is no Navigation specific wrapper around the Activity Result APIs.

Comment: thank you. i ended up using registerForActivityResult() and it worked well. but i wonder i can use Activity with Navigation component?? the reason what i say is that some people use only fragments with a single activity and the others use both Fragment and Activity at the same time. it depends on own my situation?

Comment: Your navigation graph only exists within a single activity, so while you can [create an activity destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-create-destinations#create-activity), consider that as exit point, moving to a completely separate activity that is independent from the first one. There's very few reasons why you'd purposefully want to **choose** to use multiple activities, the few cases are explained in the [Single Activity video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU).

Comment: thank you so much! i'm going to check that video :)

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the response of Detail Activity in Main Activity.

By the way, The navigation component is designed for apps that have one main activity with multiple fragment destinations. So in your case, you should convert your `DetailActivity` to `DetailFragment`. Then you can use [OnBackPressedDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back) to communicate between `ProductListFragment` and `DetailFragment`

Comment: but it also looks like Navigation component supports activity.